# TYPO3 - Error 500 in right panel of Filelist

Tags: typo3

Friend gave me access to TYPO3 CMS of his page to make some changes and I can not open Filelist.
The left panel with directories is displaying but on the right, a have error 500 message in IE or in Chrome just empty frame.
I did some modifications to that page some time ago and everything was working fine then.
Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Without the concrete error, e.g. from error log, nobody can help as there is too less information.

Comment: in which user are you logged ? as admin or editor

Comment: Im logged as admin in Backend. Everything was working fine and it stopped responding probably after extension reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
I solved that.
I disabled that extension and then when I looked at maintenance tab on this extension i saw  something like "delete LOCAL installation of this ext".
After deleting local installation and enabling system FileList instance, everything is working just fine :)

Thank You for help.

Comment: What Version of TYPO3 are you on? Sounds like some v4 instance?

Comment: Yes. It's 4.6.9.

Comment: Then you might should consider an update - v4 is long deprecated.

Comment: I dont have access to web server. i only have BE admin rights to CMS.

Answer (score 1):

If a folder contains to much files you might get problems opening it in the file list module, as the gathering of all information and maybe creating of preview thumbnails may take longer than is granted to any php process.

If it's only the preview images you might be able to load the folder after some attempts, as sometime all preview images are generated, but as it also can be other delays because of too much files you need to **enhace the runtimelimit**
or/and you might need to restructure the files and folders.
Be aware that a moving of files with FTP/SSH might break content in the FE as you might invalidate some FAL (sys_file) records so that used files are not found any more. Better: enhance the timeout (temporarily) and move the files in the backend.

in general: if you only got a blank page you disabled all error-messages (which is ok for FE, but will leave you without hint about errors).
As a first start you could take a look in the webserver-error-log.
If you got no clues: enable errormessages in TYPO3 Install Tool (enable debug mode in "Configuration presets")

Comment: I tried again  opening Filelist and still nothing. I dont have password to install tool and there is nothing in Log in Admin Tools panel. Everytjing was wroking fine. I reinstalled Filelist extension and nothing changed ;/

Comment: Also one more thing that maybe can be important to this. I,ve got same error trying to run TaskCenter and UserStatistic.

Comment: In the TYPO3-log you will not find anything valuable for this error. deactivating/activating file-list module will not bring anything. this kind of error can not be solved/analyzed with normal admin rights. you need access to apache error log, access to install tool and maybe access to php.ini

Comment: I was told that this problem started to appear in BE just after reinstalling FileList extension. Nothing more wasn't changed.

Comment: the filelist extension is a core extension. why does it need to be (re)installed? as it is the only access to fiel resources in `fileadmin/` it is enabled by default and should be disabled only in very few installations. of cause you could disable this extension if it throws errors, but then your installation still does not work any more (or even less).

Comment: I hope there will be some solution for this. The FileList extension was just reinstalled. Its hard to believe that this ruined whole page. Without access to files via FileList its hard to develop this site.

Comment: One more thing that may be usefull. When I open "Developer information" on Extension  I see that message in Installation status:
Type of installation Local - Local extension (typo3conf/ext/) - Local for this TYPO3 installation only (dynamic).
Double installation A "System" extension with this key is also available on the server, but cannot be loaded, because the "Local" version takes precedence

Comment: That sounds like you are really messed up. `ext:filelist` is an extension from core and should not be exchanged between versions. there are some extensions in TER which are titled`filelist` (in different writings) but they have other extension keys. In any way: if you have a folder `typo3conf/ext/filelist`: remove that folder (and clear caches!). Anything in there will make you problems, probably even the copy of the original extension belonging to that TYPO3 version you are running.

Comment: I removed LOCAL installation of FileList which probably appeared after reinstallation of the extension and tha directory You mentioned. It;s working fine now. Thank You for help.